# Pandas fill cells with NaN when conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df[df['c'] == 3]['a'] = np.nan
df
>>>
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
```

Why is `0,a` not NaN? I would expect that the value in `0,a` would have been replaced by `np.nan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you create [chained indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas):

```
df[df['c'] == 3]
```

with:

```
df[df['c'] == 3]['a']
```

So after set values is not propagate new value to original DataFrame.

For avoid it use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['c'] == 3, 'a'] = np.nan
print (df)
     a  b  c
0  NaN  2  3
1  4.0  5  6
```

[More information](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).